# how can i read clickhouse's "with totals" row by gorm-clickhouse?

Tags: grails-orm, clickhouse

I want to use gorm to query clickhouse ”with totals“ data.
But gorm doesn't seem to support it？

ClickHouse/clickhouse-go can do it.
But it can't  use map[string]interface{} to receive data.

Is there a good way for gorm to find out ”with totals“？

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have asked this in gorm's repo - https://github.com/go-gorm/clickhouse/issues/157

As for clickhouse-go, this issue (https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/issues/309) which points to the WITH TOTALS tests, should help:

- https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/blob/main/tests/std/totals_test.go
- https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-go/blob/main/tests/totals_test.go

Comment: Yes,Thanks, I've seen this issue too, and clickhouse-go does support with totals. But in my project I need to use gorm to read clickhouse in order to use his log and map[string]interface. clickhouse-go does not support the map[string]interface to accept data.